# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS)

Tags: php, arrays

hi this is new problem to me, I need to use an array for parameter or argument in a function

but php shows this error T_ELipsis which from what I read is a functions arguments

**UPDATE** :
I should tell everyone, that I want to make a friendly/better url like `www.example.try/eg/10`

so I use `.HTACCESS` to redirect everything into `index.php` and get the `REQUEST_URI` and `SCRIPT_NAME` and remove the matching one from array.

then I turn `$requestURI` into array, and use one of the values for argument

so I think the problem is the arguments. here it is :

```
  $command = array_values($requestURI);

   switch($command[0])
{
case 'profile' :
    // We run the profile function from the profile.php file.
    profile($command[1]); // this is where the problem is, the argument
    break;
case 'myprofile' :
    // We run the myProfile function from the profile.php file.
    myProfile();
    break;
default:
    echo "404 Error : wrong page.";
    break;
}

//function profile
 function profile($chars)
{
   // We check if $chars is an Integer (ie. an ID) or a String (ie. a potential username)

if (is_int($chars)) {
    $id = $chars;
    echo"User ID adalah : ".$id;
} else {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($chars);
    // Do the SQL to get the $user from his username
    // ...........
    echo"username adalah : ".$username;
}


}
```

note : `function profile()` is on another php file I already included it

Comment: There's no `...` in provided code.

Comment: Show us your function profile()

Comment: And defining arguments with `...` is available since php5.6 so check your version.

Comment: @u_mulder exactly that's what makes me  confused

Comment: if you have any mysql query share also?

Comment: @Niklesh not yet, I haven't made any query yet, just `echo` to see if it works

Comment: @Rizier123 how is this a duplicate question when this is the only question specific to this problem?  `PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?` does not address this problem at all

Comment: @Citra45Abadi You either don't show us your real code or you look at the wrong file. As it is written in the duplicate you need to look at your error message and look at the correct file at the correct line.